# EmberJS Data HasMany relationship parent jon contains whole object not ids

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, has-many

EmberJS Data HasMany relationship parent JSON contains whole object not ids

```
App.Message = someParentClass.extend({
    childMessages: DS.hasMany('ChildMessage'),
    message:DS.attr('string',{defaultValue: ""})
}

App.ChildMessage = someParentClass.extend({
    message: DS.attr('string',{defaultValue: ""}),
    code:DS.attr('string',{defaultValue: ""})
}
```

and the JSON looks like this

```
{
    "message":"xyz",
    "childMessages":[{"code":"we","message":""},{"code":"uh","message":""},{"code":"wd","message":""}]
}
```

after fetching the object, code and message for child messages are undefined (not getting populated)

changing JSON in not in my hand

Please help

Comment: What version of Ember and Ember Data are you using?

Comment: Also, the fact that the objects do not contain IDs is problematic. How is ember data supposed to know which of the objects has been modified when saving, for instance?

Comment: Does your application only need to read data from the API or must it save as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got resolved.

Ember requirs id for each child objects. So from server I added id files with random number.

```
{
    "message":"xyz",
    "childMessages":[{"id":4567,"code":"we","message":""},{"id":7874,"code":"uh","message":""},{"id":5231,"code":"wd","message":""}]
}
```

it worked

Thanks